# Time series anomaly detection combined with data anomaly detection

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series

I'm working on a data anomaly detection system and I've tried so far the two following approaches:

- Supervised (one class SVM)
- Unsupervised (K-means)

But I'm having trouble to come up with an algorithm that detects date time anomalies, like for example there can't be a register with the date 12/3/2016 after the date 12/4/2013.
Can you point me to some algorithm, link, whatever that can learn the pattern in a time series that can be somehow combined with the previous approaches?

I'm not asking for a super specific solution but for an advice on some approach that might help me overcome this issue.

Comment: There are [good discussions](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-simple-algorithm-to-detect-anomalies-in-time-series-data) about this in quora.

Answer (score 4):

To apply anomaly detection techniques on time series, you might want to convert the `date` format to a list of integer number. For example, number of days to the latest date in your data. Since you're not doing real-time detection, you can use algorithms like in this [post](https://medium.com/ro-data-team-blog/ro-spends-a-significant-amount-of-money-on-commercials-especially-on-tv-e38eaac17735) to find outstanding date time points. You can use the results of the output to train SVM/K-means to validate if you want, but above algorithm should do enough for anomaly detection.